# iOS app displaying incorrect date in Mac iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, ionic-framework

I built an Ionic app and have noticed that the ipa installed into iTunes is displaying a date of 12/31/03. Where would I change that date or set it dynamically?

Here is a screenshot. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVDw1.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the date being displayed, in the Information section, What's New, Copyright, etc?

Comment: If I open iTunes --> iOS Device --> Apps --> Sort by Date Added.

The date under the App Name.

Comment: Thanks, Zaph for bearing with me. Yes it is the iTunes App on Mac. When I say "iOS Device", I mean my actual device. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/93sxVGu.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Research

I did some research and tried a lot on my own. In the end I came to following conclusions:

1. iTunes will display the "purchase date" of the app here
2. Once an update of the app is installed, the "update date" gets displayed here instead
3. For "manual installed apps" (not via the App Store), a "default date" is displayed => "12/31/03" (depending on the timezone, here in CEST timezone, I got "01/01/04" instead, but when changing to a U.S. timezone I also get the "12/31/03").

## What does this mean to your question?

I'm afraid there is no possibility of actively affecting the date being displayed here.

## How I came to those conclusions

### 1. Purchase date

When going to `iTunes` → `My Apps` → right click on an app and chose `Get Info` → `File`, it'll display the "purchase date" which is similar to the date when selecting sort by "Date Added"

[image]

### 2. Update date

After installing an app update that date will change to the update date.

#### Purchase date:

[image]

#### Update date:

[image]

### 3. Manual installed apps

For any manual installed app, I always get the same (default) date displayed here:
[image]

Note: "31.12.03" is just the german format for "12/31/03" (at this point I did change my timezone to a U.S. timezone, otherwise it showed the "01.01.04").

---

Sources:
http://forums.imore.com/itunes/312808-sort-date-now-includes-updates.html